# react-admin and connection pagination

Tags: graphql, apollo, relay, react-admin

I currently have a GraphQL API that uses connection based pagination as defined in https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/ which is what the Relay client uses.

I have looked at ra-data-graphql-simple but that expects the GraphQL server to return certain queries.

Are there any other examples of clients that would work with this format? If not is my best option to build on top of ra-data-graphql?

Thank you,
Owen

Comment: Have you managed to implement a working solution? If so, can you share it please?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was using this against a ruby graphql api which luckily the cursors generated are sequential numbers so can be used with the pagination. This isn't really a fix though. https://github.com/owenbendavies/cms/blob/master/app/webpacker/admin/routes/messages/build_message_query.js#L53

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, we don't have any relay compatible dataProviders. You'll have to implement your own, using `ra-data-graphql` as the foundation